# PHP: display user's id dynamically inside nested foreach loops

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Inside a `PHP & MySql CRUD` app that I am building, I have a table that displays data pulled from a `"users" table,` like so:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php $counter=0; foreach ($get_users as $arr){ ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo ++$counter; ?>
      </td>
      <?php foreach ($arr as $key => $value){ ?>
      <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
      <?php } ?>
      <td>
        <ul class="list-inline">
          <li><a href="view_user.php?id=5" title="User details"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Add data"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Delete user"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The last column, called "Actions", has a set of icon links for viewing, adding and deleteing data. Considerring the table's structure above, how can I write the user's ID dinamically on the line:

```
<li><a href="view_user.php?id=5" title="User details"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I just assume that The Id is on the 0th index of the `$arr` and hence you can do this

```
<li><a href="view_user.php?id=<?php echo $arr[0];?>" title="User details"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a></li>
```

Comment: Or you can use the first key of the $arr to get the Id

Comment: Actually it works like this: <li><a href="view_user.php?id=<?php echo $arr['id']?>" title="Vezi profilul pacientului"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a></li>